# GCS Transfer Service Object MD5 and CRC32C hash mismatch

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, md5

I am using GCS Transfer Service to move objects from S3 into GCS, I then have a ruby script on GAE that downloads the new GCS object and operates on it. The script fails to download because the MD5 and CRC32C hash verification fails. The verification (part of the `google-cloud-storage` gem) works by comparing the `object.md5` and `object.crc32c` hashes to the file's calculated hashes, but these are mismatched.

I downloaded the file from AWS and calculated the `md5` and `crc32c` hashes and I got the same value that the file attributes on GCS has: `object.md5` and `object.crc32c`, however when I download directly from GCS and calculate the hashes, I get different `md5` and `crc32c` hashes.

To replicate this:

1. Calculate the hash of an AWS object
2. Transfer the object to GCS via the transfer service
3. Pull the attributed GCS object hashes using:

   ```
   gsutil ls -L gs://bucket/path/to/file
   ```
4. Calculate the hashes of the GCS object

The error that I originally got was:

```
/usr/local/bundle/gems/google-cloud-storage-0.23.2/lib/google/cloud/storage/file/verifier.rb:34:in `verify_md5!': The downloaded file failed MD5 verification. (Google::Cloud::Storage::FileVerificationError)
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/google-cloud-storage-0.23.2/lib/google/cloud/storage/file.rb:809:in `verify_file!'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/google-cloud-storage-0.23.2/lib/google/cloud/storage/file.rb:407:in `download'
    from sample.rb:9:in `'
```

Comment: If you download the objects from GCS and calculate their MD5s directly, do you get "object.md5" or some other value? Have you compared one to the original to see if and how they're different?

Comment: @BrandonYarbrough yes I have tried that out, when I download directly from GCS and calculate the MD5 I get a different value than the `object.md5` value.